# tampermonkey/greasemonkey can not click a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I am working on a tampermonkey/greasemonkey script that will click a button on a webpage when the page is loaded. Here is the code for the form.

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dis-none" id="LoginBtn" value="81458">Login</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="LogoutBtn">Logout</button>
</div>
```

Here is the button id="LogoutBtn" I am trying to use to click the button. the below method is not working.

```
document.getElementById("LogoutBtn").click();
```

I am using Chrome, and in the console, I can see blow error:

```
VM1139:2 ERROR: Execution of script 'my_click_button' failed! Cannot read property 'click' of null
(anonymous) @ VM1139:2
(anonymous) @ VM1139:3
(anonymous) @ VM1139:18
(anonymous) @ VM1139:18
(anonymous) @ VM1121:2
b @ VM1121:2
E_u @ VM1121:3
u @ VM1123:60
E @ VM1123:58
create @ VM1123:67
e @ VM1123:15
```

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the script wait for the page to be loaded ?